# find the type of all variables in scope python

Tags: python, types, scope

I want to write a function which gets all the variables in a scope, and then determines the 
type of each variables. 
I am a aware of vars(), dir() and similar, but these functions return a list of strings.
How can I actually get the types ? 
I would like to do something like that:

```
 #this is just pseudo code
 for item in <items in scope>:
     if isinstance(item, someclass):
        del <item which belongs to someclass>
```

thanks in advance, 
Oz

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What are you going to do with the information? Generally, there's little reason to know the type of a variable in Python.

Comment: Added an answer, but they are very few good reasons for doing this in Python. So unless you really know what you are doing, you are better of telling us what you want to achieve so we can give you a clean way to do this.

Comment: @Roseman, you always beat me at this :-)

Comment: @Oz123: You probably misunderstood how Python frees up memory. Deleting names to free up memory is either pointless (leaving the scope would delete them anyway), useless (the values have other names and remain active anyway) or a effort to fix a very broken design (with more bad design, instead of using scopes properly).

Comment: @Jochen: I suspect the OP wants to do this in the interactive interpreter, in which case this could be useful -- see the discussion in the comments to my answer.

Comment: Sven, you are right, I wrote it in the edit I did for the answer I liked. The point is to have an Octave\Matlab like function which does the same there "clear all". I don't want %reset from ipython, because it is two comprehensive ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for `locals`, which returns a dict with locals vars name and their values:

```
for name, value in locals().items():
     if isinstance(value, someclass):
        do something
```

OK, I am editing this answer, because it is the closest of what I want:
I wanted to erase all numpy array. I find it annoying that numpy does not have "clear all" a la octave\matlab, and ipython's %reset is a bit too much ...

so, here it is:
     In [24]: anp=np.r_[1:10]

```
 In [25]: np.who()
 Name            Shape            Bytes            Type
 ===========================================================

 anp             9                36               int32

 Upper bound on total bytes  =       36

 In [26]: for name, value in locals().items():
 ....:     if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
 ....:         print name
 ....:         print value
 ....:         del globals()[name]
 ....: 
 anp
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

 In [27]: np.who()

 Upper bound on total bytes  =       0
```

Thanks for everyone, for the will and the effort!

Comment: this is almost it, it better than what i have got so far...but, del value, or del name still does not work ...

Comment: @Oz: You never mentioned you want to `del` anything.  Your design seems broken -- how about telling us what you really want to do?

Comment: i just updated my question. what I really want to do is to delete all the instances of np.ndarray (i always import numpy as np)...

Comment: @Oz123: You are not allowed to modify the local scope directly.  For the global scope, you *could* use `del globals()[name]` to delete the variable named by the string variable `name`, but you definitely shouldn't.  Morevoer, note `del` deletes names, not objects, so this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Oz123: in that case, it is better to write your own answer than to edit someone else.

Answer (score 4):

To get the type of an object, you can use

```
type(obj)
```

To get the type of each local variable, you can use

```
for obj in locals().values():
    print type(obj)
```

(In Python 3.x you should use `list(locals().values())` instead of `locals().values()` since you are modifying `locals()` during the loop.)

Comment: note, that is not what i want, because it does not help me iterate over all the items in the scope

Comment: @Oz: Maybe you have to be clearer about what you mean by "the scope".  I took it to mean "the local scope".

Comment: sven, printing the type of object is useless for most of the things. that is why i started with isinstance.

Comment: @Oz123: As suspected, this is an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  So what you are really trying to do is freeing some memory.  Do you want to do this in your program, or rather in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: I wrote it on top, i want to have a function to delete all numpy arrays, so i dont have to manually do it!

Comment: @Oz123: Do you want to do it in a program (in which case you have a design problem) or do you want to do it in the interactive interpreter (in which case you would need to mention which interactive interpreter you are using)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* the variables, you need to access both the global and local variables:

```
for (name, value) in globals().items()+locals().items():
    print "Variable", name, "is of type", type(value)
```

This gives you access in particular to the global variables that are defined automatically by the Python interpreter (like `__name__`).

If you only need to gather the types and do not need the names, you can do `.values()` instead of `.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` -

```
for item in locals():                # although locals() is a dict, you can iterate through its keys.
    obj = eval(item)
    print type(obj)                  # this prints the type of the object
    if isinstance(obj, someclass):
        # do something
```